# Don't cut badges too early

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, badges, responsive-design

Some long-named badges are truncated too early on the profile page when viewed on narrow screens (e.g., on Android Chrome):

> [image]

> [image]

Reproducible on Windows 10 desktop Chrome [as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/151385/mad-scientist):

> [image]

Could we just display them completely if there’s enough space?