# Long name of badge makes badge fat on Next Badge popup

Tags: bug, design, badges, responsive-design

When a badge with a long enough name hits into the Next Badge popup, it appears fat on a narrow screen:

> [image]

It turns out it also happening on wide screens (e.g., on [iPad Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_Pro) 11"):

> [image]

Here's clearly visible that such blocks occupy more vertical space than others.

And it's ever uglier for earned badges:

> [image]

Meanwhile, on the earned badge block of the profile page, the name shortening is used:

> [image]

See the related question: [Don't cut badges too early](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386544/339911)

Comment: This behavior looks like [tag:status-bydesign] to me. Discounting the issue in your last screenshot, which you already reported in "[Don't cut badges too early](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386544/271271)", this appears to be working properly to me. I'd **much** rather have the tag name wrap under these circumstances than have it truncated.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, I think the badge with the wrapped text is more useful because the user can see the entire string.  Of course, a tooltip can also display the entire string, but it is nice to not have to hover over the badge to see the entire string (especially for accessibility purposes).

Importantly, the badge with the wrapped text does not cause the parent element to occupy more vertical space.

To improve the badge's appearance and readability, the second line of the string could be indented so it begins directly below its first line.  Thus, the badge's colour icon would stand out. Below is a mockup of this design:

[image: Mockup of indented badge text]

Comment: I agree. I think it's a necessary evil.

Comment: Especially important, as narrow screen often means mobile, which has a touchscreen. Tooltip on hover is not possible on a touchscreen

Comment: To be fair, I think the issue being reported here is that the badge looks wider than it should be, given the line-wrapping that's happening... (Or maybe not, given the complaints of the vertical space it takes up.) But I'm guessing it looks that wide because it's the max/full width of the badge area, regardless of how much of that width is actually occupied by text?